# How to tell SCons to stop computing implicit dependencies in a particular directory?

Tags: scons

My SCons project depends on a lot of third party libs, each providing dozens or hundreds of include files.

My understanding of how SCons works is that, on each build, it parses the source files of my project to find the `#include` directives, and it uses the value of `env['CPPPATH']` to find these files and compute their md5 sum.

This scanning is costly, and thus I would like to optimize this process by teaching SCons that all the headers of my third party files will never change. This property is actually enforced by the tool that manages our third party libs.

I know there is a `--implicit-deps-unchanged` option that forces scons to assume that the implicit dependencies did not change, but it works globally. I did not find a way to restrict this option to a particular directory. I tried to find if the default `Scanner` of implicit C++ files can be configured, but found nothing. I think it is possible to avoid using `CPPPATH`, and instead only give the `-I` option to the compiler directly, but it is cumbersome.

Is there any way to optimize SCons by teaching him that files in a directory will never, ever change?

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more about how you analysed your build process to be sure that the scanning of headers is the big problem? Have you tried to rearrange the order of the include paths, such that most header files get found directly in the first try? Other than that I don't see a lot of potential for optimization, other than writing your own custom C/CPP scanner...

Comment: @dirkbaechle "Can you tell a little bit more about how you analysed your build process [...]". I know that adding the arguments `--max-drift=1 --implicit-deps-unchanged` (ie don't compute the md5 for any file) on an up-to-date build makes the execution time drop from 59s to 13s on my project. Also, we depend on ~30 3rd party libs, including Boost which is header-heavy.

Comment: Boost should be listed first in ``CPPPATH`` then. ;) You may want to check times for reading the SConscripts vs actual building with the ``--debug=time`` option. And if you're feeling very adventurous today, try out [my fastcpp Tool](https://bitbucket.org/dirkbaechle/scons_fastcpp)...but take the disclaimer page into account.

Comment: I can share some numbers now. I implemented both solutions: the naive solution where everything is in `CPPPATH`, and the solution where my third party includes are specified using the `-I` options in `CCFLAGS`. The SConc execution time for a noop build takes 168s for the naive solution, and 35s for the `CCFLAGS` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try pre-expanding the list of header file paths into CCFLAGS.
Note that doing so means they will not be scanned.

```
for i in list_of_third_party_header_directories: 
  env['CCFLAGS'].append('-I' + i)
```

In this case the contents of **CPPPATH** would be your source directories, and not the third-party ones which you assert don't change.

Note that changing the command line of your compile commands in any way (unless the arguments are enclosed in `$( $))` will cause your source files to recompile.

Comment: This is indeed the solution I was referring to when I said "I think it is possible to avoid using `CPPPATH`, and instead only give the `-I` option to the compiler directly, but it is cumbersome". This is the solution I ended up implementing in the end. Also, with GCC this lets me use `-isystem` instead of `-I` to silence the warnings from third party include files.